# Enable a child control when the parent is disabled

Tags: wpf, button, hyperlink, disabled-control

I have a Button containing a Hyperlink, like so:

```
<Button IsEnabled="False">
    <Hyperlink IsEnabled="True">Testing</Hyperlink>
</Button>
```

I need the Hyperlink to be enabled, however the Button to be disabled. How can I achieve this?

The above simply results in both controls being disabled.

Comment: What is the purpose of having a hyperlink inside a button?

Comment: @AbZy The hyperlink shows meta-information about the other content in the button (which I have omitted for brevity).  I still want the user to be able to access that meta-information even if the button itself is disabled.

Answer (score 5):

I solved this problem by creating a simple wrapper element that breaks the `IsEnabled` inheritance chain from the parent.

The framework's default coerce callback checks the parent `IsEnabled` value and inherits it. This control sets a new coerce callback that just returns the value directly without checking inheritance.

```cs
public class ResetIsEnabled : ContentControl
{
    static ResetIsEnabled()
    {
        IsEnabledProperty.OverrideMetadata(
            typeof(ResetIsEnabled),
            new UIPropertyMetadata(
                defaultValue: true,
                propertyChangedCallback: (_, __) => { },
                coerceValueCallback: (_, x) => x));
    }
}
```

In the example from the question it would be used like this:

```xml
<Button IsEnabled="False">
  <ResetIsEnabled>
    <!-- Child elements within ResetIsEnabled have IsEnabled set to true (the default value) -->
    <Hyperlink>Testing</Hyperlink>
  </ResetIsEnabled>
</Button>
```

Comment: Simple and effective solution!

Answer (score 0):

Control `Hyperlink` has strangely with the property `IsEnabled`. In addition to the one that you mentioned, namely, the full value inheritance from a parent, there is another similar.

`Hyperlink` for the specific control, which has been turned off (`IsEnabled="False"`), setting (`IsEnabled="True"`) will not update the `Hyperlink` property. The solution - use a relative source for `Hyperlink` (more [info](http://siderite.blogspot.com/2011/06/wpf-hyperlinks-and-isenabled-mystery.html)).

For solving your question, I have decided that it is not the standard way to solve. So I created a `Class` with its own dependencies properties. It has it's property `MyIsEnabled` and `MyStyle`. As you might guess from the title, the first sets its property `IsEnabled` and `MyStyle` need to specify the button style, simulating the `IsEnabled="False"` behavior.

`SimulateDisable Style`

```
<Style x:Key="SimulateDisable" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.5" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gainsboro" />

    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Border CornerRadius="4" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="DarkBlue" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="MyContentPresenter" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Define `Button` with yours properties:

```
<Button Name="MyButton" local:MyClass.MyIsEnabled="False" local:MyClass.MyStyle="{StaticResource SimulateDisable}" Width="100" Height="30" Click="Button_Click">
    <Hyperlink IsEnabled="True" Click="Hyperlink_Click">Testing</Hyperlink>
</Button>
```

`Listing of MyClass`

```
public class MyClass : DependencyObject
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyIsEnabledProperty;

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyStyleProperty;

    #region MyIsEnabled

    public static void SetMyIsEnabled(DependencyObject DepObject, bool value)
    {
        DepObject.SetValue(MyIsEnabledProperty, value);
    }

    public static bool GetMyIsEnabled(DependencyObject DepObject)
    {
        return (bool)DepObject.GetValue(MyIsEnabledProperty);
    }

    #endregion MyIsEnabled

    #region MyStyle

    public static void SetMyStyle(DependencyObject DepObject, Style value)
    {
        DepObject.SetValue(MyStyleProperty, value);
    }

    public static Style GetMyStyle(DependencyObject DepObject)
    {
        return (Style)DepObject.GetValue(MyStyleProperty);
    }

    #endregion MyStyle

    static MyClass()
    {
        MyIsEnabledProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("MyIsEnabled",
                              typeof(bool),
                              typeof(MyClass),
                              new UIPropertyMetadata(false, OnPropertyChanged));

        MyStyleProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("MyStyle",
                          typeof(Style),
                          typeof(MyClass),
                          new UIPropertyMetadata(OnPropertyChanged));
    }

    private static void OnPropertyChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Button MyButton = sender as Button;
        bool MyBool = GetMyIsEnabled(MyButton);

        if (MyBool == false)
        {
            MyButton.Style = MyClass.GetMyStyle(MyButton);
        }            
    }
}
```

Plus for the event `Hyperlink` pointing `e.Handled = true`, so that the event did not happen next.

```
private void Hyperlink_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Hyperlink Click!");

    e.Handled = true;
}

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Button Click! Don't show it's!");
}
```

`Output`

[image]

P.S. Sorry for late answer :).